# Merge CSV data into existing table

Tags: mysql, csv

I want to merge data from CSV into an already existing table that has data:

The table I already have has 4 columns, 2 of which are NULL. My CSV file has 3 columns: one is the Primary Key to be used to match the table and the other 2 have information to fill my already-existing table.

I want to be able to match the CSV's Primary Key to my table's Primary Key, and insert the information from the CSV into the matched row.

My table goes something like:

```
+--------+----------------+------+
| CardID | Topic | Number | Date |
+--------+----------------+------+
 pk00001 | name  | NULL   | NULL |
+--------+----------------+------+
```

Whereas the CSV goes like:

```
"ID","Number","Date"
"pk00001","100001","1999/01/01"
```

The table doesn't have any constraints: it's all `VARCHAR(256)`

However, my table has more rows than the CSV, and the operation shouldn't touch those rows.

Is it possible to create such a query in MySQL?

Comment: Yes it's possible. You might want to be more specific in your question.

Comment: More specific how?

Comment: Q1: What are you meaning by "_Merge CSV data into..._"? In my ears it sounds like, along the simple import of values into the table, other operations are or should be involved. Which case is it?

Comment: Q2: You say "_...the operation shouldn't touch those rows_". But this means that you just want to INSERT rows and never UPDATE anything. Is it what you say? Let's say that your table already has a record with value `pk00001` for the `CardID` column. What do you want to happen when importing, if a row with the same value exists in the CSV file too?

Comment: 1. I want to do some sort of "Inner Join" between CSV file and a table.
2. I meant that the operation should only update the rows that match their corresponding PK. For example: if theres a `pk99999` entry in my Table but there isn't one in the CSV file, that row shouldn't be modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have a function to do exactly what you're asking. There may be database clients that can do this for you, but your best bet would be to do it the old fashioned way.

First, load your csv file into a new table in your database. Most database clients will be able to do this for you, but if you want to do it from your shell, you can look at [`mysqlimport`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html) or [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).

Once your data is in your table (you may want to index the key as well, depending on the size), you can do a simple update with a join to your new table.

```
UPDATE
    original_table
SET
    CardName = new.CardName,
    CardText = new.CardText,
    -- ...And the rest of your columns to update
FROM
    original_table old
    join imported_table new
        on (old.CardID=new.CardID)
```

Then drop your csv table, and you're good to go.

---

A simple (but far more dangerous and less performant) alternative would be to open your csv file in Excel and use a formula to generate the `UPDATE` statements for you. For example:

`="UPDATE original_table SET CardName='"&B1&"', CardText='"&C1&"' WHERE CardID='"&A1&"'"`

Then just populate each row with this formula, and you'll have an update statement for every row you want to modify.

Please be aware that this Excel method is opening you up to SQL injections (both accidental, as if Card Text said "for John O'Brien", and potentially malicious if any of the csv content comes from an external source).

Comment: Can you give me an estimate of the performance of the first operation? I have about 2GB of CSV files (plural) to insert/update into the db

Comment: @DreamIT It will be pretty fast, but it's very hard to say - it depends on the specs of your server; the number of rows in both your table and your files (IE the amount of I/O required to do the join); whether there's an index on the columns being joined; whether there are any triggers or indexes that could slow down the updates. But you're probably looking at minutes (or maybe tens of minutes), not hours.